# How to shut down the 70+ systems by the one remote machine?

Tags: command-line, shutdown, remote-access

What ways are there to shut down a computer remotely?

My desktop is running Ubuntu 12.04 desktop edition and when I try to shut it down remotely, it doesn't actually work. I used the command `sudo shutdown now`. However, when I got home, I came to discover that the computer was still on stuck.

Comment: Have you tried `halt`?

Comment: have u tried to ssh to remote system then use the command init 0?

Comment: What do you mean with 70+ in the title? In the body you speak of 1 desktop system?

Answer (score 3):

This works here:

```
ssh {user}@{ip-adres} sudo poweroff
```

It will ask twice for a password unless you copy the ssh key to your remote computer and make poweroff accessible by non root user.

Make it a loop for all IP's you need (pseudo code->)

```
for host in {ip1, {ip2}, {ip3} ; do ssh $host poweroff ; done
```

Or even easier... [clusterssh](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/clusterssh) [image: clusterssh]

> ClusterSSH (cssh, crsh, ctel) allows you to control multiple ssh, rsh or telnet sessions from a single input window. You can also configure clusters of machines for easy invocation and interact with individual terminal windows during a session.

[image: Install via the software center]

Comment: should i create of one server and install the package of ssh (or) to install with ssh to all the systems