# How to run a job in several machines that have Ubuntu as operating system

Tags: software-installation, cpu, mpi

I need to run a job in several virtual machines exists in a specific cloud and I have the IP address for all of them and I configured the hostname for all of them. How to run a command in a network of virtual machine ? 
note that the script of this job divides the job into 4 steps to run in parallel since each step needs 2 thread that run in parallel on one machine, now I need to use more than one machine to run the same script in which to let a threads to perform the parallelism using all theses machines by using this command:

```
./script.py '100 digits number' slaves.hostnames=hostname1,hostname2,hostname3 --slaves 4 --client-threads 2
```

The above number is number that I need to factor using all these machines to decrease the overall execution time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What I need to install on Ubuntu to run my code on several machines](http://askubuntu.com/questions/763669/what-i-need-to-install-on-ubuntu-to-run-my-code-on-several-machines)

Comment: You do realise that a single machine can factor this number in less than a second?

Comment: @fkraiem really? What are the prime factors? I think all primes up to 10^24 is a lot.

Comment: @Tim 2, 353493749731236273014678071260920590602836471854, 4494149541356931528600221

Comment: @Tim I'm voting to close that over this, since this one has more detail, (and an answer. now :().

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to shut down the 70+ systems by the one remote machine?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/318766/how-to-shut-down-the-70-systems-by-the-one-remote-machine)

Comment: @muru Thanks for pointing to the other question. Actually it was more informative! Maybe merging them is a better idea.

Answer (score 1):

There are several tools for having a kind of "parallel ssh". As you use Python, `pssh` should be fine. Install it with `pip`:

```
$ sudo pip install pssh
```

Create a pssh hosts file like this:

```
192.168.0.10:22
192.168.0.11:22
```

and then invoke:

```
$ pssh -h pssh-hosts -l root -A echo "Hi!"
```

You will asked for your password, but you can use certificates to avoid manual entering of passwords.

See more:

http://www.tecmint.com/execute-commands-on-multiple-linux-servers-using-pssh/

**One important note:** If you want to solve a problem in parallel, you may need MPI (Message Passing Interface). I suggest [MPICH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPICH). MPI provides a standard means of communication to solve a problem collaboratively with multiple machines in parallel. Although, writing fast applications to find prime numbers/factors is nothing new.

If you have a multicore machine, use multithreading. But if you are going to use multiple computers, you will need MPI.